# Why can I inherit handles from WSASocketA and not from socket?

Tags: windows, shellcode

I'm trying to write some custom shellcode to obtain a shell from a program.
Looking at the program intermodular calls, I found a call to `socket()`, and my initial plan was to use that to create a new socket, connect back and spawn a shell.

I am able to to get a connection back, but unfortunately when I call `CreateProcessA`, I don't get any shell.

After the call to `socket()` I have the socket descriptor in EAX:

[image]

And then, after `connect()` (which works, I get the connection back on my netcat listener), I call `CreateProcessA()` and this are the parameters:

[image]

`InheritHandles` is correctly set to TRUE. On the left panel I have dumped the `StartUpInfo` structure and as you can see the file descriptor is correctly added for all handles (first 3 bytes of the structure are all set to 200). Also the flag `STARTF_USESTDHANDLES` is correctly set.

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. What surprises me is that if instead of using the address of the intermodular call to `socket()`, I use the address of `WSASocketA` (found using arwin), and without changing anything else (apart from adding the extra null arguments required for WSASocketA), I can get my shell.

I don't understand why this is not happening with `socket()`, in fact, according to the documentation for the flag `WSA_FLAG_NO_HANDLE_INHERIT` of the `WSASocketA`:

> Create a socket that is non-inheritable.
>
> A socket handle created by the WSASocket or the socket function is
>   inheritable by default. When this flag is set, the socket handle is
>   non-inheritable.

So I assumed that by default it should work with both functions.

I don't know if this is relevant, but I'm testing it against a Windows 7 machine.

Comment: This isn't really a reverse engineering question. My guess would be that - given you compare WinSock with the socket implementation inherited from BSD - that's your answer right there ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows `socket()` creates a socket with `WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` flag set and inheritable by default.

Windows `WSASocket()` allows you to specify `WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` and `WSA_FLAG_NO_HANDLE_INHERIT`.  If you **omit** both flags to `WSASocket()`, then the resulting socket will be inheritable and will not have `WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` flag set.

Unlike on Unix, Windows `SOCKET` is different from file descriptors or pipes.  If you pass a socket to Windows `CreateProcess` using `STARTF_USESTDHANDLES`, the socket **must not** have `WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` flag set.

You managed to (accidentally) use `WSASocket()` without flags, so created an inheritable socket without `WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED`, so it worked for you!